# Unable to connect to wifi network. Android

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to connect to the wfi network which I have scanned. For testing I am giving ssid and key to wifi configurration and connecting to the network but in device its not getting connected.

Using following method to connect to the network.

```
fun connectToANewWifiNetwork() {
    val wifiConfig = WifiConfiguration()
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", "GK")
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "Sid_GK_2417")
    val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)
    wifiManager.reconnect();
    ProgressDialogUtils.getInstance().hideProgress()
}
```

Also is there any way to detect if we are connected to the given network?

What am I doing wrong here..?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Android 10 or higher, you'll need to switch to using the `WifiNetworkSpecifier` mechanism, which requires user interaction in order to connect. For example:

```
val specifier = 
  WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .setSsid("GK")
    .setWpa2Passphrase("Sid_GK_2417")
    .build()

val networkRequest =
  NetworkRequest.Builder()
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
    .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
    .build()

val networkCallback = object : NetworkCallback() {
 override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
   // Connected to network here
 }
}

context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class)
  .requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder?hl=en#build()

Comment: I am getting the dialog with the specified wifi id and connect option on that when I click connect I am getting toast as connection succsessfull but not getting internet access on wifi icon it shows cross as it does not have internet access.

Comment: If it's not a hotspot network, you probably need to remove the line that removes NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET.

Comment: tried removing the same still its not getting connected fully. shows no internet access. Can't we connect to wifi programatically after android version 9 pie? I am now testing on android 10. nothing is working

Comment: I have the same issue here. I connects to the hotspot but it doesn't have internet. I'm using API 29.